# Cannot debugging asp.net on IIS7 by attaching process w3wp

Tags: asp.net, debugging, iis-7, w3wp

I have a asp.net website in VS2008 which I have pre-compiled in local directory which is virtual directory for IIS 7（http://machinename:83）

when i 
1. launch http://machinename:83/
2. VS2008-->debug-->Attach to Process..-->select w3wp.exe
3. set the breakpoint in code in VS2008
4. run app

while i found it cannot go to the breakpoint. (i m sure the breakpoint must be run)

anybody can help me on this?

Comment: Do you have any output in the **Output** (from _Debug_) window when you attach to the w3wp.exe or is it blank?

Answer (score 5):

What you're doing should work, but you can try this, which is frequently used to debug Windows services upon startup:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

Just put it on the line where you want to start debugging, and the OS will prompt you to attach.

Comment: This rocks... It's slow, it's a pain to do over and over and it's amazingly effective because you don't have to know anything about the process your code is running in.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the Publish Web Site feature in Visual Studio, then make sure that the 'Emit debug information' checkbox is checked.

Comment: thanks, this pointed me in the correct direction. In VS 2012 there is a drop down for release/debug in the publishing profile.

Answer (score 3):

Please endure you don't have Optimize Code option tuned on, in the web config and in the Property's -> Build -> **Optimize code  is OFF**

[image]

in web.config

```
  <compilation debug="true" batch="true" optimizeCompilations="false" />
```

Answer (score 2):

make sure your web.config is set with

```
<compilation debug="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are publishing, make sure that you are publishing with debug configuration
(was my case on VS-2015)
[image]